# Why does Promise.any require at least one input?

Tags: promise, bluebird

Does anyone know why `Promise.any()` requires the array to be non-empty?

This code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.any([]).then(function () {
    console.log('something')
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log('err:',err)
})
```

Gives this error:

> RangeError: Input array must contain at least 1 items but contains only 0 items

Comment: Probably because passing any empty array doesn't make any sense? Obviously if you pass none, there won't be any to succeed.

Comment: That's not how Promise.all handles getting passed an empty array.

Comment: The [documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html) states that `any()` waits for 1 fulfilled promise in the argument array before being fulfilled itself. You can't get 1 fulfilled promise from an empty array.

Comment: Promise.all is not like any, think it as similar to multiplication by zero vs division by zero